# "Invalid column name" In SQL Server from OpenQuery to SSAS with flattened results

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

I run the following query in T-SQL with LINKED_AS being my SSAS.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED_AS, 
    'SELECT FLATTENED PredictTimeSeries([PredictColumnName], -3, 0) 
      FROM [Foo]') AS a
  ) AS b
```

and everything works perfect.

But if I want to use just one of the returned columns (it returns PredictColumnName and $TIME), how do I access them?

```
SELECT PredictColumnName FROM
  (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED_AS, 
    'SELECT FLATTENED PredictTimeSeries([PredictColumnName], -3, 0) 
      FROM [Foo]') AS a
  ) AS b
```

does not work, and I've tried a lot of combinations with alias and such, but haven't managed.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@Niklas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/885817/niklas)' question post.

> Found out the answer, the way to select is like this
>
> ```
> SELECT b.[Expression.PredictColumnName] FROM
>   (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED_AS, 
>     'SELECT FLATTENED PredictTimeSeries([PredictColumnName], -3, 0) 
>       FROM [Foo]') AS a
>   ) AS b
> ```
>
> I got confused by "." being a part of the column name.